# wbash -- checking if directory has folder and corresponding file

Tags: linux, bash

I'm new to bash, and I'm trying to see if my directory contains a folder its corresponding txt file. Not all the folders have a corresponding txt file, and the directory has a lot of folders and txt files, so I wanted to have it automated.

example dir:

```
a_1/
a_1.txt
b_1/
b_1.txt
c_1/
c_1.txt
d_1/
```

I understand how to check if a file or folder exists within a directory separately. But I'm having trouble checking if the folder its corresponding txt file exists in the directory.

I wanted something where it would print out folder exist but the file doesn't. 
From the above example, it would print for files that do have their corresponding folder: `folder a_1/ and a_1.txt both exist` and don't have their corresponding txt file:  `d_1/ exist but txt file doesn't.`

This is what I currently have, but it doesn't seem to be working. :(

```
#!/bin/bash
for x in *; do
    if [[ -d  "$DIRECTORY" ]] && [[ -f ${f%.txt} ]]; then
        echo -n "$x ${x%%.dir}.txt are both present ";
    else
        echo "directory '$DIRECTORY' existed but didn't find txt file"
```

Comment: For starters: you never close `for` loop; inside your loop, you use three variables: `$DIRECTORY`, `$f` and `$x`, but only `$x` is actually defined (assuming this is entire code).

Comment: @MirosławZalewski thanks for pointing that out! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your specification, the script corrected:

```
#!/bin/bash

for x in *; do
    if [[ -d "$x" ]]; then
        if [[ -f $x.txt ]]; then
            echo "$x and $x.txt are both present "
        else
            echo "Directory '$x' exists but $x.txt doesn't"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment on the above reply, the double [[ and ]] are not necessary.  Also, you can denote the present working directory using a period (a bash trick that also works on the command-line by the way):

```
for x in .; do
    if [ -d ${x} ]; then
        ...
    fi
done
```

You can also specify a path from the commandline:

> ./myprog.sh /Volumes/myflashdrive/filedir

```
path=${1}

for x in ${path}; do
    if [ -d ${x} ]; then
        ...
    fi
done
```